# Windows Forms application responds very slowly when Visual Studio debugger is attached

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I recently changed my work computer and I'm struggling developing with Visual Studio 2019.

This is a simple operation that highlights the problem. This happens when application is in debug mode with debugger attached.

[image]

As soon as I detach the debugger (Debug > Detach all in VS) the speed returns to normal. Speed is OK also with the installed version of the software. I tried using the Performance Profiler to see where the time is going but since the debugger is not attached in that configuration speed is fine there too.

[image]

I must add that only some operations, like the one pictured, are incredibly slow. In many cases the application runs as smooth as the installed version.

I've compared every option under Tools > Options > Debugging with my previous computer and one colleague and they match perfectly. The operating system is the same, Windows 10, and the installed version of VS is the same.

I tried cleaning the build, removing the .vs folder, repairing Visual Studio with no luck. I've always used a desktop PC (my last one was an I7 8xxx), the new one is a laptop with Ryzen 7. Other colleagues have a laptop with Intel processors and they show no issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no obvious reason for this, the debugger only steps in when it has to.  Look in the Output window for an excessive number of notifications.  Next, try it with anti-malware temporarily disabled.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion @HansPassant I was able to trace down where the problem was. I had indeed a ton of notifications in the output window echoing a logger running behind the scenes. The logger itself isn't slow, it is the VS listener that slows everything down.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Hans Passant in a comment, this was due to an excessive amount of lines written in the debug window. Lines of log written to an external file (via an Enterprise Library logger) were echoed in the debug window, so I think the whole process was waiting for that window to be constantly updated.